# How to refresh just a part of Android UI component?

Tags: android

For example, an android UI consists of a textView, an imageView and a gallery, when I update the text on the textView and the image on the imageView, the gallery also update automatically. The problem is that the thread will reload the image used by the gallery and affect the performance. What I want is to just refresh the textView and the imageView, but not the gallery. How can I achieve this?

Comment: it's not clear?can you describe more?

Comment: Thank you for your comment， @Henry. What I mean is that according to the Android default implement, if there is a component such as a button get refreshed(for example, call "setText" to change the text on the button), all the UI component will be refreshed and the problem is described as above. And I want to just refresh part of all the components. Is this detailed enough?

Comment: you can you View.invalidate(rect) with 'rect' is a rectangle that bound the place you want to update and 'View' is the parent view or the big one contain the place you want to update

Answer (score 1):

sounds to me like you need to be using [`View.invalidate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29)